# How to Update a Route in Apple Maps - Xcode Swift 5 in iOS 13.0?

Tags: swift, xcode, maps, swift5, apple-maps

I'm working in a MapApp like Uber but I need to Update the Polyline overlay. The problem is I can't find any method or event that responds to updating the route.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit                                                 
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var StopRoute: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet var mapa: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PlayRoute: UIBarButtonItem!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var localization: CLLocation?
    var anotationCounter: Set<MKPointAnnotation> = Set<MKPointAnnotation>()
    var destinationMapItem: MKMapItem?
    var destinationMarker: MKPointAnnotation?
    open var destinationImage: UIImage?

    //Control
    var routeNum: Int = 0
    var onPathfinding = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.mapa.delegate = self

        //Autorización para jalar el mapa
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        //Mostar current location
        mapa.showsUserLocation = true
        mapa.showsScale = true

        //Update curent location
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        //Tratando Datos
        UserLocation()

        let tapPressRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapPress(_:)))
        tapPressRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        mapa.addGestureRecognizer(tapPressRecognizer)

    }

    func UserLocation(){
        //trata de mantener actualizado lat y long siempre que sus valores sean != de nil
        localization = locationManager.location
        let latitude: Double? = localization?.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude: Double? = localization?.coordinate.longitude
        mapa.userLocation.title = "Tu ubicación"
        if let lat = latitude, let long = longitude{
            //inforrmación extrra
            mapa.userLocation.subtitle = "(\(lat); \(long))"
            AdjustMap(location: localization!)

        }
    }

    //Funcion que ajusta la pantalla y la centra en la ubiacacion
    func AdjustMap(location: CLLocation){
        let coordinatesRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: localization!.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)

        mapa.setRegion(coordinatesRegion, animated: true)
    }

    //Encontrando el camino al punto designado y toma como parametro la cantidad de rutas que quiero
    func Pathfinding(routeNum: Int){
        //Limpia mapa y toma mis coordenadas
        self.mapa.removeOverlays(self.mapa.overlays)
        let coor = locationManager.location?.coordinate
        let start = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coor!))

        //var routeArray = Array<MKDirections.Response>()

        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = start
        request.destination = destinationMapItem
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
        request.transportType = .automobile


        let tracking = MKDirections(request: request)
        tracking.calculate(completionHandler: {(routes, error) in
            if let out = error{
                print("Error \(out)")
                return
            }
            else if let rutas = routes?.routes
            {
                self.mapa.addOverlay(rutas[self.routeNum].polyline, level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)
            }
        })
    }

    //Definiendo el gesto de toque corto sobre la pantalla
    @objc func handleTapPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if !onPathfinding
        {
            //LimpiaMarca anterior
            if destinationMarker != nil{
                mapa.removeAnnotation(destinationMarker!)
            }

            let tapLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: mapa)
            let coordinates = mapa.convert(tapLocation, toCoordinateFrom: mapa)

            destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinates.latitude, longitude: coordinates.longitude)))

            destinationMarker = MKPointAnnotation()
            destinationMarker?.coordinate = coordinates
            mapa.addAnnotation(destinationMarker!)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func PlayRoute(_ sender: Any) {
        if !onPathfinding
        {
            onPathfinding = true
            Pathfinding(routeNum: routeNum)
            print(onPathfinding)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func StopRoute(_ sender: Any) {
        if onPathfinding
        {
            onPathfinding = false
            print(onPathfinding)
            self.mapa.removeOverlays(self.mapa.overlays)
        }
    }

    //Defininiendo la línea de traceo
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange
        renderer.lineWidth = 5
        return renderer
    }
}
```

I've defined a couple of buttons to start/end Pathfinding function but I need to update the Route over time.

I was looking for it in Apple's Docs and Web but I can't find that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to register a CLLocationManagerDelegate and then have the function

```
optional func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

Then you can update your route if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip iCyberPaul. It works amazing recalculating the route. I tried before with time stuff but this is much better. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I am glad it worked, could you please mark this as a correct answer. Thanks.